# Is it possible in google sheets to convert a list of numbers into a sequence of numbers and ranges?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet in which one column contains a whole bunch of numbers (anywhere from 000 to 999) but not all of them are listed. I use a formula:

```
=regexreplace(regexreplace(trim(join(",", sort($C$4:$C))),",+", ","),",$","")
```

to convert the column of numbers, like:

```
001
006
005
000
008
023
007
```

into a sorted comma-separated list:

```
000,001,005,006,007,008,023
```

Which is all well and fine, but it starts getting rather lengthy when more and more numbers are entered and I'd love to find a way to condense it by numerical ranges, e.g.:

```
000,001,005-008,023
```

Is there any way to do this within google sheets?

If it's a function - I'll be happy if you point me to which function and I'll look at the help for it, I just cannot think of what it would be called (I already looked at "sequence" and looked through a list of everything that seemed to match "range" - but didn't see anything that looks like it would do what I want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(",", SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(
 TO_TEXT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE("×"&JOIN("×", 
 TEXT(SEQUENCE(MAX(A1:A*1)+1, 1, 0), "000")), JOIN("|", FILTER(
 TEXT(SEQUENCE(MAX(A1:A*1), 1, 0), "000"), NOT(COUNTIF(A1:A, 
 TEXT(SEQUENCE(MAX(A1:A*1), 1, 0), "000"))))), ), "××", 0)), 
 "^×|×$", ), "×(.+)×", "-"), "000"), "×", ",")))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow!  Excellent! I don't know if I ever would have come up with that on my own.  I'm going to have to spend some time understanding all the pieces so I'll have more in my toolbox for the future, but this is perfect. Thanks much!